# Why is vcvarsall.bat not installed with Visual Studio 2008 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7-x64

I just installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Express, and in the folder
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools
I have the following files:

```
VDT\
errlook.exe
errlook.hlp
makehm.exe
vcvars.txt
vsvars32.bat
```

Where is vcvarsall.bat???

Background: I am compiling Python 2.7 modules for Windows 7 on x64 architecture. Most come with setup.py scripts that will fail if vcvarsall.bat is not found. There are hundreds of posts dealing with how to fix this issue by installing Visual Studio 2008, supplementing with the Windows SDK if using Visual Studio 2008 Express. However, my installation does not include vcvarsall.bat in the expected directory!

Comment: It is normally in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC directory.  But Express is special, for one I don't think it even uses that install folder by default.  For another it isn't really made to run stuff from the command prompt.  I don't think you get the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" shortcut in the Start menu folder either.  You're kinda using the wrong edition to do a programmer's job.

Comment: @HansPassant are you basically saying that there's no free option to build Python modules in Windows?

Comment: @Nick-T, others have had success with VS2008 Express for Python 2.7 32-bit, but 64-bit appears to be out of the question.  I've had to rely on pre-compiled binaries that a number of sites are hosting for this very reason. The MinGW-w64 project has made recent progress improving Win7 support, so that may also be an option.